# TensorFlow while_loop parallelization TensorArray

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't exactly understand how the while_loop parallelization works. Suppose I have a TensorArray having 10 Tensors all of same shape. Now suppose the computations in the loop body for the first 5 Tensors are independent of the computations in the remaining 5 Tensors. Would TensorFlow run these two in parallel? Also if I use a Tensor instead of a TensorArray and made the updates to it using scatter_update, would it pass the gradients properly during backprop?

Comment: If you know the loop is going to be performed always the same number of times, then I think it is better to create a graph. Loops only make sense, in my opinion, when you don't know in advance the number of iterations and other special cases. You can also try the map function.

Comment: I don't know the number of times the loop will be performed in advance. I just presented a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get the parallel execution of the first 5 iterations and the second 5 iterations. I can say for sure if you provide a code sample.